# Deletion doesn't work for interactive report in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I created an interactive report in APEX 5, and the CRUD operations work just fine. However, today, I find that the delete and update operations don't work anymore. When I hit the delete button, it just redirects to the main page as usual, and the there is a notification on the top right corner saying that Action Processed. However, that row is not really deleted. I checked the delete button, and the action is set to SQL DELETE action by default. I suppose I didn't touch any settings and the delete and update just simply don't work anymore, I am wondering if there is any way I can debug my app, so that I can find the problem here.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can hit debug in the developer toolbar, then do the delete action then hit View debug.  Another option is to hit 'Errors', there might be a database error that occurs on delete that you can see there.

Comment: Any javascript code on same page if yes kindly make sure this line stays at very top of "Function and Global Variable Declaration" 
=> var htmldb_delete_message='"DELETE_CONFIRM_MSG"';